# Django login() authenticate always returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I have this code written up and it correctly registers users, though when it comes to the login function, it only works for the superuser i have in the database. Every time I try to log in a user that i greated using the register form, authenticate returns None.

I'm having it print the form data and can confirm that the form being submitted has accurate info, yet it fails authentication every time unless i login the superuser.

**Views:**

```
def register(request):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reg_form(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user = Users.objects.create(
                username=username, email=email,
                password=password, phone=phone,first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name
            )
            try:
                user = Users.objects.get(phone=form.cleaned_data.get('phone'))
                print("User exists")
            except Users.DoesNotExist:
                print("DoesNotExist")
                return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': reg_form})
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'profile.html')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': reg_form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': reg_form})
           

def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = log_form(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                print("user exists")
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'profile.html')
            else:
                print("user does not exist")
                print(form.errors)
                return render(request, 'login.html', {
                    'form2': log_form
                })
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
        })
```

**Register form:**

```
class reg_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = { 'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

**Login form:**

```
class log_form(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=64)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: How does password for other users look in database, did you properly use create_user in your Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the user is actually getting created in the database or not if the user is not getting created then make following changes to your **register** method:

use 'Users.objects.create_user' method instead of 'Users.objects.create', please find below link for more details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/

Also hash your password as Willem is suggesting.

Comment: The user is definitely being created, I've checked in admin. Though the passwords are being saved as plain text after having implemented the above answer

Comment: If you use 'Users.objects.create_user' method then you don't need to use 'set_password', please try by using 'Users.objects.create_user' method and remove 'set_password' and let us know.

Comment: account manager class had a create_user function in it, while i was calling user.objects.create, instead of create_user. Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The password should be *hashed*: in Django the passwords are *not* stored in a readable format, but it stores the hash of that password. This concept is discussed in the [*changing password* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords).

This thus means that for your `reg_form`, you save the object with:

```
class reg_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = { 'password': forms.PasswordInput()}

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        return user
```

This is a very simple version of a more advanced form: the [**`UserCreationForm`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) perhaps it makes more sense, like [@iklinac says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551300/django-login-authenticate-always-returns-none/67551348?noredirect=1#comment119399216_67551348), to subclass from that form, and slightly alter it to your specific model and fields.

Comment: I would just include some resources :)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

Comment: I have updated the form accordingly, but it still stored the passwords as plain text in admin, while my superuser's password is hashed. And it also continues to return None. This is with fresh migrations

Comment: @beatmaister: did you subclass from the `UserCreationForm`? Likely then you only need to specify the model, and the fields, and the logic of hashing the password will be done by the `UserCreationForm`. You should also work with `form.save()`, and not fetch it from `form.cleaned_data['...']`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am not using a userCreationForm, but you gave me the idea to check my account manager class which was the issue. I was calling create, instead of create_user